# Promise and Resolve not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test1");

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo',{
    text: String,
    complete: Boolean
});


const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  }
  type Todo{
      id: ID!
      text: String!
      complete: Boolean!
  }
  type Mutation{
      createTodo(text:String!): Todo
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (_, { name }) => `Hello ${name || 'World'}`,
  },
  Mutation:{
      createTodo: async (_,{ text }) => {
          const todo = new Todo({text, complete: false});
          await todo.save();
          return todo;
      }
  }
};

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })

mongoose.connection.once("open", function() {
    server.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'))
  });
```

Hello I'm new to node js and mongoDB. I'm trying to start my server but it's not starting. Every time it shows a error like this:

```
(node:17896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Every time this is showing some promise error.Can anyone please help me to debug this program. I m a beginner. I don't know much of it. But as per my understanding, I have written correct code only.

Comment: Well there is no `try..catch` here. Using `async/await` does not obviate the need for exception handling. The error is likely coming from the `save()`. You also really should be doing `await mongoose.connect(...)` from inside an `async` block as well. Commonly an IIFE as a "main" block.

Comment: Also it's kind of pointless code. A function which contains async operations "always" returns a Promise anyway. So you may as well just `return todo.save()` and thus you don't need the `async`. `createTodo()` of course requires a Promise to resolve either way.

Comment: Can you please show me buddy. How to proceed with the async/await function @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0):

Probably your save function throws an arrow which you don't handle it!
you can solve this issue with one of these ways:

GraphQL handles promise by itself, so this would give you same result:

```
createTodo: (_,{ text }) => {
      const todo = new Todo({text, complete: false});
      return todo.save();
}
```

using `try catch` would give you better error handling:

```
   createTodo: async (_,{ text }) => {
      const todo = new Todo({text, complete: false});
      try {
           await todo.save();
           return todo;
      } catch(err) {
           \\ do something with error
           console.error('error=>', err);
           return null;
      }
  }
```